# While I enter data through a form and submit , firebase gets the image but details of other data didn't get on the firestore collections

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

Image can be seen on the storage of firebase .Error is `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name') at submitPortfolio` .But it fails to add data.Once a error in the line `` const storageRef = ref(storage, `portfolio/${image.name}`); `` seems .But now it didn't.I don't know why!

> firebase.js

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth";
import { getStorage } from 'firebase/storage';
import { getFirestore } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: ",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: ""
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth();
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
export const db = getFirestore(app);
export const storage = getStorage(app);


export const signInWithGoogle = () => signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
```

> login.js

```
import { signInWithGoogle } from '../../firebase';
import React from 'react'

const Login = () => {
    return (
        <div className="dashboard">
            <button onClick={signInWithGoogle}>
                Sign in with google
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Login;
```

> index.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { getAuth, onAuthStateChanged } from 'firebase/auth';
import Home from "./home";
import Login from '../Login';
import React from 'react';

const Dashboard = () => {

    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    const auth = getAuth();

    useEffect(() => {
        onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
            if(user) {
                setUser(user);
            } else {
                setUser(null);
            }
        })
    }, []);


    return (
       <div>
           {user ? <Home /> : <Login />}
       </div>
    )
}

export default Dashboard;
```

> Home.js

```
import { useRef } from 'react';
import { auth, storage, db } from '../../firebase';
import { ref, uploadBytes, getDownloadURL } from 'firebase/storage';
import { addDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { collection } from 'firebase/firestore/lite';

const Home = () => {
    const form = useRef();

    const submitPortfolio = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const name = form.current[0]?.value;
        const description = form.current[1]?.value;
        const url = form.current[2]?.value;
        const image = form.current[3]?.files[0];

        const storageRef = ref(storage, `portfolio/${image.name}`);

        uploadBytes(storageRef, image).then(
            (snapshot) => {
                getDownloadURL(snapshot.ref).then((downloadUrl) => {
                    savePortfolio({
                        name,
                        description,
                        url,
                        image: downloadUrl
                    })
                }, (error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                    savePortfolio({
                        name,
                        description,
                        url,
                        image: null
                    })
                })
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error);
                savePortfolio({
                    name,
                    description,
                    url,
                    image: null
                })
            }
        )
    }



    const savePortfolio = async (portfolio) => {
        console.log(portfolio)
        try {
            await addDoc(collection(db, 'portfolio'), portfolio);
            window.location.reload(false);
        } catch (error) {
            alert('Failed to add portfolio');
        }
    }

    return (
        <div className="dashboard">

            <form ref={form} onSubmit={submitPortfolio}>
                <p><input type="text" placeholder="Name" /></p>
                <p><textarea placeholder="Description" /></p>
                <p><input type="text" placeholder="Url" /></p>
                <p><input type="file" placeholder="Image" /></p>
                <button type="submit">Submit</button>
                <button onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>Sign out</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Home;
```

Comment: Can you try `console.log(image)` before `storageRef` and share a screenshot of the output ?

Comment: Output was the name of the image file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using the wrong variable for the storageRef. You declared the variable name but use image.name

Change in submitProtfiolio the storageRef to:

```
      const storageRef = ref(storage, `portfolio/${name}`);
```

Comment: can you share code.